# Updating PSObject hash table in loop

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Here is a part code of uploading data by FTP

```
foreach ($line in $FTPServer)
    {
        Start-Transcript -Path $results            
        Write-Host -Object "ftp url: $line"
        If (Test-Connection $line -Count 1)
        {

            Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FTPCredential -Server $line -Session MySession -UsePassive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            $Session = Get-FTPConnection -Session MySession
            if($session.UsePassive -eq "True"){$connect="OK"}
            else{$connect="!!!-FAIL-!!!"}

            foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem .\Upload))
                {
                    Write-Host -Object "Uploading $item..."
                    $Send= Add-FTPItem -Session $Session -Path $FTPPlace -LocalPath .\Upload\$item -Overwrite -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                    if($Send.Name -eq $item.Name){$Rec="OK"}
                    else{$Rec="!!!-FAIL-!!!"}
                    $array = $line, $item, $connect, $Rec
                    $FailTable=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{"FTP Server"=$array[0]; "File"=$array[1];"Connected"=$array[2];"Uploaded"=$array[3]})

                    $FailTable|Out-File -Append '.\stats.txt'
                }
        Stop-Transcript
        } Else {"$line">> .\DownServers.txt}
    }
```

`$Failtable` is a hash-table that stores ip of FTP server (`$line`), name of uploaded file (`$item`), status if connected (`$connect`) and upload status (`$Rec`). The hash-table is piped to file `.\stats.txt` The problem is in every iteration to .\stats.txt are saved headers like that:

```
FTP Server  File                    Connected Uploaded    
----------  ----                    --------- --------    
192.168.1.1 ConfigurationDivide.xml OK        !!!-FAIL-!!!



FTP Server  File     Connected Uploaded    
----------  ----     --------- --------    
192.168.1.1 test.txt OK        !!!-FAIL-!!!
```

So I need that to be one under another and autosized like that:

```
FTP Server  File                    Connected Uploaded    
----------  ----                    --------- --------    
192.168.1.1 ConfigurationDivide.xml OK        !!!-FAIL-!!!    
192.168.1.1 test.txt                OK        !!!-FAIL-!!!
```

I tryed to put hash-table declaration  `$FailTable=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{"FTP Server"=$array[0]; "File"=$array[1];"Connected"=$array[2];"Uploaded"=$array[3]})` before loops and then- in the loops add values (`$line`, `$item`,...), but there aren't in hashtable `.add` method.

Comment: I think the problem is about place of declaration $FailTable - it is inside foreach loop and every iteration causes the headings are write again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have FailTable created outside the loop, you are creating and appending an entire new PSCustomObject each loop to the file.

try implementing this:

```
$FailTable = @()
#Example loop
for($i =0;$i -lt 5; $i++){
        #Inside the loop add new object to the array
        $failTable += @{"FTPServer"=$i;"File"=$i;"Connected"=$i;"Uploaded"=$i}
}
 #foreach hashmap in the array cast to a PSCustomObject (which gives you the headers you want)
 #and then Select-Object The order you want them in.
$FailTable.foreach{[PSCustomObject]$_} | Select-Object "FTPServer", "File","Connected", "Uploaded" | Out-file test.txt
```

Edit:

PowerShell v2+ compatible version:

```
$FailTable = @()
$objTable = @()
#Example loop
for($i =0;$i -lt 5; $i++){
        #Inside the loop add new object to the array
        $failTable += @{"FTPServer"=$i;"File"=$i;"Connected"=$i;"Uploaded"=$i}
}
 #foreach hashmap in the array cast to a PSCustomObject (which gives you the headers you want)
 #and then Select-Object The order you want them in.
foreach($fail in $FailTable){
    $objTable += New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $fail

}
$objTable | Select-Object "FTPServer", "File","Connected", "Uploaded" | Out-file test.txt
```

Comment: This is what I mean. PSCustomObject gives a needed output. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Like am said- it works correct, but when I move it to Win Server 2012 (I run this on Win 7 before) I get a error:                                                   
At line:9 char:23
+ $FailTable.foreach($_){[PSCustomObject]$_} | Select-Object "FTPServer", "File"," ...
+                       ~
Unexpected token '{' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: It should be the opposite of that, this answer should work on PS v4 and up (Win Server 12+)

Comment: In the Error I see "$FailTable.foreach($_){[PSCustomObject]$_}". It should be "$FailTable.foreach {[PSCustomObject]$_}".  The {} in powershell denotes a script block and is needed if you want to use "$_" expression to reference the current object being iterated through.

Comment: OK my stake. I appended $_ for checking something. Regardless there is the same error. I think you have right about PS version, because on Win 7 I have v5 and on Server is v3.

Comment: Made a version compatible with PowerShell V2, that should work on V3 fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, different answer :)

Try this:

```
$FailTable = @()

$spam = New-Object PSObject
$spam | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'FTP Server' -Value ""
$spam | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'File' -Value ""
$spam | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Connected' -Value ""
$spam | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Uploaded' -Value ""

$FailTable += $spam
$FailTable | Out-File -Append '.\stats.txt'

foreach ($line in $FTPServer)
{
    Start-Transcript -Path $results
    Write-Host -Object "ftp url: $line"
    If (Test-Connection $line -Count 1)
    {

        Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FTPCredential -Server $line -Session MySession -UsePassive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $Session = Get-FTPConnection -Session MySession
        if($session.UsePassive -eq "True"){$connect="OK"}
        else{$connect="!!!-FAIL-!!!"}

        foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem .\Upload))
            {
                Write-Host -Object "Uploading $item..."
                $Send= Add-FTPItem -Session $Session -Path $FTPPlace -LocalPath .\Upload\$item -Overwrite -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                if($Send.Name -eq $item.Name){$Rec="OK"}
                else{$Rec="!!!-FAIL-!!!"}

                $spam = New-Object PSObject
                $spam | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'FTP Server' -Value $line
                $spam | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'File' -Value $item
                $spam | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Connected' -Value $connect
                $spam | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Uploaded' -Value $Rec

                $FailTable += $spam
                $FailTable | Select-Object -Last 1 | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-File -Append '.\stats.txt'
            }

    Stop-Transcript
    } Else {"$line">> .\DownServers.txt}
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I wrote it like that because I what to stay within you logic that status file is updated as something happened. If you want to have autosize work you need to put all information into the file after everything happened. Remove line 10 and 38 and last line `$FailTable | Out-File -Append '.\stats.txt'`

Comment: Hej Michał. Thanks for advice. Maybe you know something about Get-Telnet also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841308/no-effects-in-running-telnet-get-telnet-in-powershell